# Flash players not working on chromium

Tags: 14.04, flash, chromium

I have installed both Adobe flash player and Pepper flash player on Ubuntu 14.04. But I can't watch any Facebook videos on chromium. what might be the problem?

Comment: How have you installed Pepper Flash Player? Does `chrome://plugins` show the flash player?

Comment: I installed on software center. But doesn't show the  Pepper Flash Player in chrome://plugins

Comment: I followed the updated advice [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash) only to see flash on firefox, but **not** on Chromium :-(

Comment: my favor is chromium. The only problem is flash