# flash player not working on Ubuntu 14.04 with Chrome for Linux

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash, chromium

My flash player isnt working anymore on my Xubuntu 14.04 and Chrome for Linux but it is working on Firefox.
I did several researchs on internet, and haven't found any solution yet. 
I removed adobe flash player, tried pepperflashplugin-nonfree, restarted browser and machine several times.

my chrome plugin is configured like that at the moment :

```
Adobe Flash Player - Version : 21.0.0.213
Shockwave Flash 21.0 r0
Nom :   Shockwave Flash
Description :   Shockwave Flash 21.0 r0
Version :   21.0.0.213
Emplacement :   /home/nicolas/.config/google-chrome/PepperFlash/21.0.0.213/libpepflashplayer.so
Type :  PPAPI (hors processus)
    Désactiver
Types MIME :    
Type MIME   Description Extensions de fichier
application/x-shockwave-flash   Shockwave Flash 
.swf
application/futuresplash    Shockwave Flash 
.spl
```

I had a look here : [Flash player not working in 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452489/flash-player-not-working-in-14-04-lts) and here : [Flash players not working on chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637222/flash-players-not-working-on-chromium) but no solution was working now, maybe it is obsolete...

Thanks

Comment: This is happening for Chrome on other platforms as well. I've started a thread on Adobe's forums: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2134046

Comment: probably the same issue yes, let s hope someone will hear about us

Comment: As I know, chrome uses an embedded flash player module, so (un)installing flash-player modules in the OS doesnt matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last update of Chrome fixed it!